# std::list<std::shared_ptr>::erase got an SIGSEGV

Tags: c++, list, stl, shared-ptr

Consider following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <memory>

class Foo;

class Foo {
  public:
    Foo(int i): id(i) {}
    typename std::list<std::shared_ptr<Foo>>::iterator i2;
    int id;
};

int main() {
  std::list<std::shared_ptr<Foo>> l;
  auto f1 = std::make_shared<Foo>(1);
  f1->i2 = l.end();
  l.insert(f1->i2, f1);
  std::cout << f1->id << std::endl;
  std::cout << l.size() << std::endl;
  for (auto i: l) {
    std::cout << i->id << std::endl;
  }
  auto t = f1->i2;
  l.erase(t);
  std::cout << l.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Executing these code will get an SIGSEGV at `l.erase(t)`，seems ListNode were destroyed before shared_ptr decrease its ref_count. Why？How to fix it？

Answer (score 1):

After insert your `f1->i2` left `l.end()`. You try to erase `l.end()`, that is not allowed.

Fix is simple. Change the line where `insert` called:

```
f1->i2 = l.insert(f1->i2, f1);
```

Comment: Inserting into a `list` will not invalidate iterators, but otherwise you're spot on: attempting to `erase end()` is invalid.

Comment: @Tas you can google specific implementation where `std::list::end()` invalidated after insert to the end.

Comment: I'd consider that an edgecase. It's pretty rare that I cache `end()` and I can't think of a time where I've cached `end()` when there was the possibility of removal. That would be asking for a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Iterator,initialized before insert/remove operation, may be in an indeterminate state after the operation and should be updated again. Also you are trying to delete a node in the list through an iterator which itself is pointing to list.end(). For deleting the last element of a list, you can rather use `std::list.pop_back();`

```
auto t = f1->i2;
l.erase(--t); // Change this in your code - decrease the iterator
```